# How to set custom CSS property for distributed content

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to set the custom CSS property of the PaperMenu node passed as content. 
`--paper-menu-background-color:green;` works in the main document or when the PaperMenu is part of my custom component and are not in distributedNodes().

I have the following main.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_menu_button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_submenu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_badge.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/my_p/my_menu_bar.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>
<my-menu-bar>
    <paper-menu>
        <paper-submenu>
            <paper-item class="menu-trigger">Topics</paper-item>
            <paper-menu raised class="menu-content">
                <paper-item>Topic 1</paper-item>
                <paper-item>Topic 2</paper-item>
                <paper-item>Topic 3</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </paper-submenu>
    </paper-menu>
</my-menu-bar>
  <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want the below in the main.html though it works:

```
<style is="custom-style">
     :root{--paper-menu-background-color:green;}
</style>
```

my_menu_bar.html

```
<dom-module id="my-menu-bar">
  <style>
    :host ::content paper-menu{
      display:inline-block;
      top:0;
      vertical-align: text-top;
    --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    <!--Does not work, setting colors via script-->
    }

  </style>

  <template>
    <div id='my_menu_bar_div'>
    <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

css below take effect but not '--paper-menu-background-color:green;'

> display:inline-block; top:0; vertical-align: text-top;

Setting background color via dart script and reflection works:

```
@HtmlImport('my_menu_bar.html')
library m_p.lib.my_menu_bar;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_menu.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_submenu.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_item.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';
import 'dart:mirrors';


@PolymerRegister('my-menu-bar')
class MyMenuBar extends PolymerElement {
  MyMenuBar.created() : super.created() { }
  void _recursive_set_style(var e, String attrName, String value){
//    print(reflect(e).type.superclass.toString());
    if(!(reflect(e).type.isSubtypeOf(reflectClass(HtmlElement))))
      return;
//    print('ya, it\'s subtype of HtmlElement');
    InstanceMirror helperMirror = reflect(e.style);
    var methodsAr  = helperMirror.type.instanceMembers;
    var sym = new Symbol(attrName);
    print(methodsAr[sym]);
    if(null !=methodsAr[sym]){
      helperMirror.setField(sym,value);
    }
    for(var ie in e.children){
      _recursive_set_style(ie,attrName,value);
    }
   }

  attached() {
    super.attached();
    new Future(() {
      ContentElement ce = Polymer.dom(this.root)
          .querySelector('content');
      PolymerDom dom = Polymer.dom(ce);
      List<Node> nodes = dom.getDistributedNodes();
      nodes.removeWhere((n)=>!(n is PaperMenu));
      //Setting colors
      updateStyles();
      for(var e in nodes){
        _recursive_set_style(e,'backgroundColor','rgb(156, 58, 53)');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Personally I like scripting over css, but love to know the standard way to do this and why this is happening.

### Edit

Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer's comment, the function is now reduced to:

```
void _recursive_set_style(var e, String attrName, String value){
    e.attributes[attrName]=value;
    for(var ie in e.children){
      _recursive_set_style(ie,attrName,value);
    }
  }
```

As to wrapping the content tag, it did not work or I'm doing something silly still.

### Edit2

Hi, Günter Zöchbauer. 
If you can help me confirm this, that would be great. 
It's so hard to be sure about anything.
my-menu-bar:

```
<dom-module id="my-menu-bar">
  <style>
    :host ::content paper-menu{
      display:inline-block;
      top:0;
      backgroundColor:black;
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      vertical-align: text-top;
    }
    :host ::content .special{
      <!--setting class name did nothing-->
      display:inline-block;
      top:0;
      backgroundColor:black;
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      vertical-align: text-top;
    }
    :host div#my_menu_bar ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    :host #my_menu_bar_div > ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    :host #my_menu_bar_div ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    #my_menu_bar_div ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    :root ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    :root #my_menu_bar_div ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    :host ::content .paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }
    :host ::content #paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
    }

  </style>

  <template>
    <style>
      :host ::content paper-menu{
      display:inline-block;
      top:0;
      backgroundColor:black;
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      vertical-align: text-top;
      }
      :host ::content .special{
      <!--setting class name did nothing-->
      display:inline-block;
      top:0;
      backgroundColor:black;
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      vertical-align: text-top;
      }
      :host div#my_menu_bar ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      :host #my_menu_bar_div > ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      :host #my_menu_bar_div ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      #my_menu_bar_div ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      :root ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      :root #my_menu_bar_div ::content paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      :host ::content .paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
      :host ::content #paper-menu{
      --paper-menu-background-color:green;
      }
    </style>
    <div id='my_menu_bar_div'>
    <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

I tried debugger and it seems CSS variable sham and related values are taking effect before initPolymer() and standard CSS directives like "display:inline-block;".

### Edit3

Hi, Günter Zöchbauer.
In response to your "This doesn't look right.", I double checked.
But I think css variable sham is the thing to blame. I mean, as I said first, the standard CSS directives are working on the distributed content.

> Under shady DOM, the `<content>` tag doesn’t appear in the DOM tree.
>   Styles are rewritten to remove the ::content pseudo-element, and any
>   combinator immediately to the left of ::content.

The description is a little lacking, but from examples I assume it's telling me to have selectors to the right and the left of the ::content pseudo element and I think I always had that right.
Digging deeper requires javascript knowledge and I don't have that, I know javascript is the foundation of web but I'm no web programmer and want to cover wide before diving deep, so I will give up on this.

```
<dom-module id="my-menu-bar">

  <template>
    <style>
      :host .content-wrapper > ::content div{
        /* These CSS variables do not work*/
        --paper-menu-background-color:blue;
        --paper-item{
          background-color:red;
        }
        /*The below works alright*/
        /*background-color:green;*/
        /*color:red;*/
      }
      :host .content-wrapper > ::content .special{
        /* This and the above should have
        the same scope of selection, but this one
        does not work at all.
        Encapsulation playing a trick idk.*/
        /*background-color:green;*/
        /*color:red;*/
      }
      :host ::content div{
        /*works*/
        /*background-color:green;*/
      }
      :host ::content {
      /* does not work*/
        /*background-color:green;*/
      }

      :host ::content paper-menu{
        /*works but custom property and color*/
        /*color:blue;*/
          display:inline-block;
          top:0;
          vertical-align: text-top;
      }
      :host ::content paper-item{
        /*works*/
        /*color:blue;*/
      }
    </style>
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
    <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

### Edit4

After a long and futile search, I believe I found it.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/?redirect_from_locale=pt

> What's conceptually bizarre about insertion points is that they don't
>   physically move DOM. The host's nodes stay intact. Insertion points
>   merely re-project nodes from the host into the shadow tree. It's a
>   presentation/rendering thing: "Move these nodes over here" "Render
>   these nodes at this location."

```
You cannot traverse the DOM into a <content>.
```

If I could set the value of a CSS variable for an outer light dom from within a shadow dom, that would break the encapsulation. While Color etc belongs to content pseudo element, css variables and mixins are macro that insert values into css place holders.

Comment: Using mirrors in browser applications is usually a bad idea, it leads to code bloat (huge dart2js output size). I think what you do can easily be achieved without mirrors. `if(e is HtmlElement)` and `e.setAttribute(attrName, value)` (or `e.attributes[attrName]=value;` should do the same.

Comment: Can you please add your new version with the wrapped content tag?

Comment: This doesn't look right. See my updated answer. I removed code not related to your question to make it more cear.

Comment: Your code still doesn't have the content-wrapper element.

Comment: I am truly sorry but what do you exactly mean by content-wrapper? "<div class='content-wrapper'><content></content></div>" looks like wrapped.

Comment: See `<div class="content-wrapper">` in my answer and how it is referred to in the CSS selector.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer Dear sir, thank you for your comment. But I have already tried removing :host (theoretically it makes no difference) and using .special to select the outer most wrapper of the distributed node. Using .special in place of div somehow fails, so a simple div or paper-menu is the only option. As you can see in Edit3, I have the selector ":host .content-wrapper > ::content .special" and I did try ".content-wrapper > ::content .special";needless to say I also have a div with the class name special wrapping paper menus in the main.html. I think edit4 is the answer.

Comment: sorry, I think I overlooked that in Edit3, maybe because of the `:host` prefix. I guess your conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in shady DOM (default) you need to wrap the `<content>` tag in another tag and include this wrapper in the selector. 
See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#styling-distributed-children-content (first example for more details) 
If this still doesn't work it might be a limitation of the CSS variables shim.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      /* styling elements distributed to content (via ::content) requires */
      /* selecting the parent of the <content> element for compatibility with */
      /* shady DOM . This can be :host or a wrapper element. */
      .content-wrapper > ::content .special {
        background: orange;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="content-wrapper"><content></content></div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```